# Tagging posts to custom taxonomies using XMLRPC in R

Tags: xml-rpc

I'm using *R* to upload posts onto Wordpress using *XML-RPC* using the `newPost` function from the [RWordpress](https://github.com/duncantl/RWordPress) package.

The function call I'm using is:

```
newPost(
    content = list(
        description = postContent, 
        title = ttl, 
        categories = category_desc, 
        mt_keywords = keywords
    ), 
    publish = TRUE
)
```

I've just created custom taxonomies for my posts but am unsure how to tag those within the function call. Can anyone please advise?

For example, I have a custom taxonomy named "Monkey Type". I want to be able to tag it under the term name "Chimpanzee". Understand that the `newPost()` function uses `metaWeblog.newPost`. `wp.newPost` allows tagging of posts to custom taxonomies through the terms and terms names parameter but I'm unsure how to supply the relevant struct in *R*.

Comment: For example, I have a custom taxonomy named "Monkey Type". I want to be able to tag it under the term name "Chimpanzee". Understand that the newPost() function uses metaWeblog.newPost. wp.newPost allows tagging of posts to custom taxonomies through the terms and terms names parameter but i'm unsure how to supply the relevant struct in R

Answer (score 0):

It looks like custom taxonomies aren't supported by `metaWeblog.newPost`.

For self-hosted WordPress installs, one could try to use this hook, to adjust the tagging of posts added with `metaWeblog.newPost`:

```
/**
 * Fires after a new post has been successfully created via the XML-RPC MovableType API.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @param int   $post_ID ID of the new post.
 * @param array $args    An array of arguments to create the new post.
 */
 do_action( 'xmlrpc_call_success_mw_newPost', $post_ID, $args );
```